# New Galaxy A10e Galaxy install gets 250mbps over WiFi then slows down to 30mbps after mainstream apps install (nothing special). Why?

Tags: applications, wi-fi, lagging

I factory reset my Galaxy A10e then immediately install Ookla's Speed Test app. Over Wifi I get 100 to 200mbps on repeated tests.  After installing basic mainstream apps like Spotify, Pandora, etc and updating Google's and the Samsung phone's preinstalled apps the Ookla Speed Tests give me a maximum speed of approx 30mpbs.  I have to factory reset my phone and not install apps to keep the higher speed.  What gives?

Comment: I would assume that this is coincidence that you get high values after factory reset. What access point/Wifi router do you use (which Wifi version doe sit support)? Do you have a connection on 2.4GHz or 5GHz? How far are you away from your Wifi access point when testing? How many other Wifi networks are around you (Wifi is a shared media, if other Wifis on the same frequencies are quite active this decreases your speed).

Comment: Ok I factory reset my phone again then installed all my apps one by one while running a speed test between each installation.  I found that after I install Pandora Radio that's when the slowdown occurred.  I uninstalled Pandora Radio then rebooted my phone and the problem went away.  The Pandora Radio App seems to be causing the problem.  I suspect malware may be in the app or poor security design.

Comment: I guess Pandora Radio gives modern meaning to the term "Pandora's Box"

Comment: Is this an app from Google Play? If yes please post the link to the Play Store app page so that other users who also run into this problem can identify the app without doubt.

Comment: Yes.  Open up Google Play Store app right after you factory reset the Galaxy A10e phone and install Pandora Radio.  That is what I did and that is what caused the problem.  I installed no other software from any other source.

Comment: Can you please add the direct link to the app in Google Play? Because the name does not uniquely identity the app.